# Georeferenced labeling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, georeferencing, pdf

I have a problem with ArcMap that somehow affect georeferencing.

I have three layers, two with .lyr and one is a raster data.

The two .lyr datatypes are a border and cities with names. I georeferenced the raster  using the border and the cities and everything went well. But what I want to do now is to combine the two .lyr datasets with my raster so I can export the Raster with the overlayed border and the cities as a pdf.

Is that possible?

I already tried dissolve, merge, package etc. but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

This should be straightforward to do. Make sure that your raster and vector layers are drawing in ArcMap and then use **File | Export Map** with **PDF** as your output format.